# Cakephp 2 call a model function from view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

is it possible to call a model function directly from a view in Cakephp 2?
I know I could call it from controller and set the value to the view, but if I could call it in the view it would be better...

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it goes against the whole point of the framework and core MVC principles.

Just don't do it.

Comment: Ok, but if I call it from controller and set the var to the view, it is right, or?

Comment: Yeah. That would be right.
If you really need some model functionality in a view, you can get yourself a helper to just implement those methods from the model. Helpers are, in my opinion, not really part of the views as more something outside of the whole pattern. This is not very good implented in cake. Maybe I am completly wrong with doing such things, but I don't see a sense in implementing a logic at least two times.

Comment: "going against the whole point" and "just don't do it" is not an answer. It's a lecture on religious principle, which does not solve the problem.

Comment: -1. While I agree with the statement in this answer, this is not a valid answer to the question. Since it answers a different question, I flagged this answer to be removed.

Comment: @Seb Probably worth it being deleted. I guess past me from 5 years ago didn't have the energy to write a discourse on MVC design patterns, software design smells, refactoring and potential solutions. You should write up a better answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Can using in View same in Controller:

```
    App::import('Model', 'Department');
    $this->Department = new Department();
    $users = $this->Department->getUserOfDepartment($id);
```

Comment: This is not a good practise and it breaks the intended responsibility of the View and makes it behave more like a Controller. This results in a tightly coupled View to the Model, which in turn creates hard to maintain code.

Comment: Negating the downvote because he answered the question, even if it's not good to do, at all, in any capacity.

Comment: It may not be a good practice, but the alternative is to duplicate the model code somewhere accessible to the View, and duplication of code is also a bad practice, considering the maintenance nightmare that can create. Given the choice of Bad Practices, I'd rather have a single copy of the code.

Comment: Thumbs up for an answer that not only answers the question, the solution actually works. The MVC zealots can battle over why it's a bad idea, in the mean-time, some of us have projects to complete.

Answer (score -1):

Just to extend @DavidYell's answer a bit.
Calling a Model directly from a View really is against "whole point of the framework and core MVC principles" but if you need dynamic data in the views just fetch the data with an AJAX call to the Controller. The "pattern" is as follows:

1. Initialize a AJAX request to the Controller (lets say to the `fetchData()` method.)
2. In that method handle the request:

   - Validate
   - Set layout to "ajax" (you will have to create it)
3. Get the data you need from the Model with a call from the Controller:

   $this->UsedModel->find();
4. Return the data you just fetched to the view by rendering (for example) an JSON response

Now the data will be available in the View and you'd have kept with the "good practice". Actually exposing any Model in a view is very very bad. Don't do it please, or switch to .NET.. :D

Comment: This answer is not related to the question. @user1686123 is asking how to access Model methods during server-side rendering of the View. Your answer is related to client-side partial rendering via AJAX.

Comment: So actually you are still calling the Model code from the View, except you're adding network overhead.

Comment: @UncaAlby reallisticly yes, but it really depends on what you want to do.
If you want dynamic data - this is the way to go but one could also 'preload' the data by setting it as a view variable before rendering.

As you can see I am saying that this should not be done at all and just providing an alternative to this.